# Why is tmp\kotlin-classes folder empty and path not found during compile stage of kotlin module build in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, compiler-errors, kotlin

The module (not the main app) won't build because it fails this step:

:compileDebugKotlin

**ERROR MESSAGES**:
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

Cause: [Path-deleted-for-SO-post]\message-classes\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\com[Path-deleted-for-SO-post]\ble\aux\AlarmResponseTypes.class **(The system cannot find the path specified)**

File being compiled at position: file://[Path-deleted-for-SO-post]/message-classes/src/main/java/com/[Path-deleted-for-SO-post]/ble/_aux/AlarmResponseTypes.kt

---

Does it have anything to do with the "_aux" in src path vs "aux" in build path?

**When I look in tmp\kotlin-classes folder, it's empty.** The rest of the parent path back to C drive that I deleted for this post is correct.  Even when I try to make the folder path, it gets deleted as soon as build runs of course.

**Things I've tried many times**:

Clean - rebuild - restart - etc.
Invalidate - restart - etc.
Updated kotlin plugin, Android Studio, Gradle versions, etc.
Only building this module and not entire app.

Always comes back to same error.

AND, it did build properly (although I did not run or build into apk file after that) before updating kotlin plugin -- but not sure that had anything to do with it.

**Versions, etc.**:

AS - 3.1.3
kotlin_version = '1.2.50'

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

---

Full build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'  
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'  
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {  
    compileSdkVersion 27  
    defaultConfig {  
        minSdkVersion 23  
        targetSdkVersion 27  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"  
        testInstrumentationRunner  
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  
    }  
    buildTypes {  
        release {  
            minifyEnabled false  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
        }  
    }  
    // project configuration  
    sourceSets {  
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'  
    }  
}

dependencies {  
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')  
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"  
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED: Windows does not allow folder name of "aux"** (this is a legacy reserved word)...

Therefore, code modules that worked on Macs failed to build when incorporated into a different project on the Windows machine I was using.

As soon as a folder is placed on the file system in Windows via unzip, etc., with the name "aux" then **Windows automatically changes the folder name to "_aux"** w/o telling the user.